# Конструкция ()(). Как работает?

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 куска кода:

1.

```
var foo = {
  bar: function(){ return this.baz; },
  baz: 1
}
typeof (f = foo.bar)();
```

2.

```
var f = (function f(){ return "1"; }, function g(){ return 2; })();
typeof f;
```

В первом случае ответ `undefined`. А втором - `2`.

Не могу понять, почему ответы именно такие. Вероятно, из-за того, что не понимаю, как работает выражение `()()`. Прошу объяснить.

Comment: а примеры вроде неравнозначны. если первый должен быть похож на второй, то там должно быть `f = (foo.bar)();
typeof f;`  и тогда будет работать одинаково

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Дело в том, что я бы сравнил первый больше с IIFE, но меня напрягло то, что там сразу 2 функции, да еще и через запятую. А во втором - результат присвоения должен возвращаться (как я думаю). Но обе один похожи, поскольку это "какой-то код внутри скобок, с (trailing, не знаю, как перевести) скобками".

Comment: Во втором не `typeof f`, а `f` будет 2. А `typeof f` будет `number`.